# PassKit Pass - Opening iOS app from a pass

Tags: ios, swift, wallet, passkit

I noticed a few `PassKit` wallet passes can open their originating app, right from the pass. The iOS app opens when the pass **icon** is clicked, for example in Delta Airlines passes.

I can't seem to find any documentation or examples on this. How can one add this to a `PKPass`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `appLaunchURL` key in the passes’ pass.json.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH2-SW1

Comment: how can I test opening the url? When I click the icon it popup my app's App Store page, not my development app installed